# JSON exported data are formatted to scientific notation instead of flat

Tags: datagrip

when I export my query result to json on datagrip 2018.2 , I have my json that contains 1.0E8 instead of 100000000.
How can I export my values flat instead of scientific notation automatically formatted by JSON-Groovy?

Else I will have to patch my data manually but I think it is a bit dangerous to format a data like that, especially with a value that won't match an integer type once extracted!

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39681707/240443). tl;dr: JSON has no integer type, just number type which is generally expected to correspond to `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and it might be fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7019
Anyway, you can play with the extractor by your own. Scripts are usually located in Scratches and Consoles/Extensions/Database Tools and SQL/data/extractors. Or you can select Go to scripts directory in the extractor menu to navigate there. The problem you've described is likely here:

[image]

UPD: Here's the extractor with the fix https://gist.github.com/moscas/793e441b12872b8339a1471966343439#file-json-groovy-withnumbersfix-json-groovy