# Why does my JSON change type when published on the internet?

Tags: java, json, android-studio

When I upload my JSON the int (or possibly long) changes to a decimal number.

The JSON is uploaded to https://api.myjson.com/bins/p6ngw
After it is uploaded, the raw data still displays the correct number, but under the JSON tab the number has changed to a decimal number. You can see for yourself it you use the link.

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{"id":57646786307395936680161735716561753784,"from":"3/13/2015 8:00:00 AM","to":"3/13/2015 1:00:00 PM"},{"id":259939411636051033617118653993975778241,"from":"1/3/2015 12:30:00 PM","to":"1/3/2015 1:00:00 PM"}]
```

As an example, the first `id` is changed to `5.7646786307395935e+37`

Obviously this makes it impossible to retrieve the JSON. If I just change the id to a single number (like 1), I can retrieve the JSON, so something is strange with the id number.

Comment: That tool probably handles all numbers using double precision, and a number of 38 digits exceeds the max precision of doubles.

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but an explanation: [JSON integers: limit on size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13502497)

Comment: Ah, I see. But how do I get around it?

Comment: Represent the `id` as a String instead (only in JSON, you can convert it back to BigDecimal or long or whatever it needs to be for your backend system internally).

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks @Thilo