# Why json number changed, when do json.parse a string?

Tags: javascript, json, string

```
let string = `{"access_token": "someThingsHere", "user_id": 17841436766171705}`;

let resultObject = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(resultObject);
```

Output:

```
{access_token: "someThingsHere", user_id: 17841436766171704};
```

Here 'user_id' was changed. But why? Please help me and describe it.

Comment: IEEE-754 double-64 only has ~17 relative digits of precision. For INTEGERS, this is a distinct range with a positive limit of ~2^53, which is less than a native int64 (2^64) type. Ideally the source would use an OPAQUE STRING instead of a number. Up to int32 is OK.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13502497/2864740 — a limit is not “strongly” specified in JSON, although keeping integers to int32 will avoid JSON <-> JS transform issues such as that encountered. Some providers like Json.NET will work just fine with int64. (Very few languages support an int53 as a discrete limit, so such is less of an interesting breakpoint.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because the value is too high for JSON.parse(), take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin).

Comment: thank you for reply. Please let me how to solve it?

Comment: @MasumBillah as some people have suggested already, you could treat the user_id as a string instead, so you are able to parse it correctly. I assume that you are not going to make arithmetic operations with it, so it would not modify your app at all.

Comment: @sromeu your good suggest. I think it's just a string, then solved it.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is your id is higher than `Infinity` or `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, and Javascript overflows the number.

The good news is the input has a string type, so we can manipulate it as-is with a Regex. We just have to append quotes around the number so `JSON.parse` will interpret this as string

```js
let string = `{"access_token": "someThingsHere", "user_id": 17841436766171705}`;
string = string.replace(/("user_id":\s?)([\d]*)/, '$1"$2"');

let resultObject = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(resultObject);
```