# Why java LONG_MAX is not same with vue axios data?? How to fix that?

Tags: java, vue.js, axios

I am using java 8 for the backend and Vue CDN(2.5.16) for the front-end. My codes are giving below

**BACKEND API**:

```
@RequestMapping(mapping = "/get-long-max", requestMethod = RequestMethod.GET)
private long getLONG() {
  System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
  return Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

**Front-end:**

```
getLongValue() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get-long-max.do').
  then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.payload);
    return response.data.payload;
  }).catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Whenever I call the function from the client-side. The Long_MAX is not the same for both ends.
Java `system.out` shows the value `9223372036854775807` and the front end value is `9223372036854776000`.
[image]

Please help to fix it. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**:

When I hit the URL directly on the browser it seems ok [image]

Comment: It looks like the value got converted to a float along the way.

Comment: I assume it ceiled on the 4th digit from right

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `long` data type, all numeric values are `double`. The 64-bit maximum value of `9223372036854775807` gets truncated to `9223372036854776000` in a `double`, since it only has 53 bits for the value.

Comment: @Andreas it's weirder. 9223372036854775807 is an actual double value. try it.

Comment: @Tuhin you need to try 9223372036854775806 as well. 9223372036854775807 is a blessed number (it is representable by iEEE doubles), 9223372036854775806 isn't.

Comment: @rzwit  I'm only using the static constant in `Long.class`

Comment: @tuhin47 and by using only that one, you're not seeing the full picture. You have a copy paste feature, use it: Put in `9223372036854775806` instead of `Long.MAX_VALUE`. And don't just check the browser console's 'response' text field, check in javascript.

Comment: I have changed the value as you said and `console.log` the value. Still, the same issue remains.

Answer (score 2):

All longs whose value exceeds plus or minus 2^53 will suffer from this, as the concept 'long' isn't a thing in javascript land / not a thing in JSON, it's all `double` over there.

One fix is to always pass double, at which point the java side, too, would show `9223372036854776000` (above 2^53 and below -2^53, the distance between any 2 consecutive numbers that the `double` type can represent is greater than 1.0, i.e. not every integral number is representable any more).

Another is to ensure all your numeric needs fit within -2^53 and +2^53.

A third is to pass all data a strings.

You can see this purely in java code, too:

```
long x = Long.MAX_VALUE;
double d = x;
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println((long) d);
```

this prints:

```
9223372036854775807
9.223372036854776E18
9223372036854775807
```

<del>I was expecting that last one to be 9223372036854776000, but I guess 2^63-1 does so happen to be a representable double</del> (EDIT: See below), but note that the second print is the e-notation form of the number you are seeing in javascript. Also note this snippet:

```
long x = Long.MAX_VALUE - 1;
double d = x;
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println((long) d);
```

this prints:

```
9223372036854775806
9.223372036854776E18
9223372036854775807
```

Note how there is now a difference between the first and third print. <del>So, whilst I have no explanation for why you are seeing 9223372036854776000</del>, it's almost certainly because of float/double conversion and rendering issues, and there is **no way** to fix that; you cannot losslessly convert a long to double or float and back to long, as the second snippet shows, so the solution is not to do that, but, `long` does not exist in JSON, so you'd have to either avoid the problem range (above and below ±2^53) or transit this data in string form.

EDIT:

I figured out the weirdness inherent in the code examples. Turns out, the double value *is* in fact 9223372036854776000. However, when you cast that number to a long, you get 9223372036854775807 again - this is in hindsight obvious, as that's the closest long value (it is also the highest possible long value). In fact, `long big = (long) 1e300;` would also get you that value. As for @Tuhin47 - you need to test the 'path' that your number takes from your java code to your javascript code with something else: This number (9223372036854775807) has the property that if you convert it to a double and then back to a long, that you get the same number back, which means you may think it's working when it really isn't. Use 9223372036854775806, which has the property that if you convert it to a double and back, that you get a different number out.

Comment: *"not a thing in JSON"* is incorrect. JSON doesn't specify a precision limit to numeric values, though the specification allows *implementations* to do so, like JavaScript treating all numbers as `double`. E.g. Java could use `BigDecimal` to support arbitrarily large precision numbers.

Comment: I update my question. The value seems ok when it's called directly without Axios.

Comment: @rzwitserloot *Wikipedia:* "JSON **was** based on a subset of the JavaScript scripting language (specifically, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition—December 1999[17]) and is commonly used with JavaScript, but it is a **language-independent** data format." --- *RFC 7159 - The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format:* "This specification **allows** *implementations* to set limits on the range and precision of numbers accepted." --- The spec itself does not limit the precision of numbers. JSON is not JavaScript, regardless of the name, it's a language-independent standard.

Comment: And yes, I'm being pedantic, because you're misinforming people who don't know better (which apparently includes you too, and wasn't just a typo), and so I try to clarify that. Would you rather we leave incorrect information in the StackOverflow repository? Programming requires accuracy in what we write, and the information we use when programming should be accurate too. *"not a thing in JSON"* is incorrect, so I pointed that out. To say it correctly, you could say *"not a thing in JavaScript's implementation of JSON"*.

Comment: @rzwitserloot no, it’ll do fine in l, say, *Python*, provided you set the decoder to use the `Decimal` type to decode JSON numbers, or in *Rust*, where serde’s Number type supports 64 bit float or integer interpretations. The central gist is: *wether or not it’ll go well depends on your JSON decoder and language support for large numbers*. Yes, it’ll go badly in JavaScript. But that’s not a JSON issue.

Comment: `2^63-1 does so happen to be a representable double` no, 2^63-1 has 63 significant bits so obviously it can't be represented in double

Comment: this answer is appropriate for the first part of my question. Still, I expect someone may give a solution for that