# .NET6 REST API long.MinValue and long.MaxValue serialization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, swagger-ui, system.text.json

Seems .NET suffers the same problem with `long.MinValue` and `long.MaxValue` as Java

described in this post: [Why java LONG_MAX is not same with vue axios data?? How to fix that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402932/why-java-long-max-is-not-same-with-vue-axios-data-how-to-fix-that)

Both samples use System.Text.Json

Spinning up a console app

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp
{

    public class LongValue
    {
        public long Min { get; set; }
        public long Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            LongValue longValue = new LongValue();
            longValue.Min = long.MinValue;
            longValue.Max = long.MaxValue;

            Console.WriteLine("min: " + longValue.Min);
            Console.WriteLine("max: " + longValue.Max);

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
            options.WriteIndented = true;

            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(longValue, options);

            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }

}
```

Gives the following console output

```
min: -9223372036854775808
max: 9223372036854775807
{
  "Min": -9223372036854775808,
  "Max": 9223372036854775807
}
```

Spinning up a Web App REST API with this controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{

    public class LongValue
    {
        public long Min { get; set; }
        public long Max { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class LongValueController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetLongValue()
        {

            LongValue lv = new LongValue();
            lv.Min = long.MinValue;
            lv.Max = long.MaxValue;

            Console.WriteLine("min: " + lv.Min);
            Console.WriteLine("max: " + lv.Max);

            return Ok(lv);
        }

    }

}
```

Delivers console output

```
min: -9223372036854775808
max: 9223372036854775807
```

and JSON result displayed in the Swagger UI

```
{
  "min": -9223372036854776000,
  "max": 9223372036854776000
}
```

Where in the pipeline could the difference be hidden?

The problem arises when those wrong values are coming back to the API and it complains it can't be converted to long.

---

Since some moderators felt to delete this tiny (but important) information from the answers:

Calling the endpoint with Chrome directly gives the option to view it parsed or raw.

Parsed is wrong.

[image]

Raw is correct.

[image]

Seems not be an issue of .NET6

Comment: How are you getting the JSON result? Is it coming from Postman or similar? Javascript has a max value of 9223372036854776000.

Comment: A double max value is 2^63.  You are exceeding the max and the number is getting rounded.

Comment: @jdweng No it isn't, double max value is 1.7976931348623157E+308

Comment: JavaScript can’t parse that number without loosing precision https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: @DavidG : It is the precision of the number.

Comment: @jdweng No it isn't, it's the Javascript in the browser that handles numbers differently. Stop making things up.

Comment: @DavidG : Well JAVA is then rounding when greater than 2^63 from what I found on the web.

Comment: @jdweng What does Java have to do with anything?

Comment: @DavidG : OPs link says "JAVA".

Answer (score 0):

As Everyone mentioned, This is because of precision. Simply Javascript Can't handle (Parse) numeric field as big as that or it loose precision. you can just put it in string and then send it to page like this :

```
public class LongValue
{
    public long Min { get; set; }
    public long Max { get; set; }
    public string MinString { get; set; }
    public string MaxString { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        LongValue longValue = new LongValue();
        longValue.Min = long.MinValue;
        longValue.Max = long.MaxValue;
        longValue.MinString = long.MinValue.ToString();
        longValue.MaxString = long.MaxValue.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("min: " + longValue.Min); // -9223372036854776000
        Console.WriteLine("max: " + longValue.Max); // 9223372036854776000
        Console.WriteLine("min string: " + longValue.MinString); // -9223372036854775808
        Console.WriteLine("max string: " + longValue.MaxString); // 9223372036854775807

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.WriteIndented = true;

        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(longValue, options);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

You Can Clearly see the difference here. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Don’t post code as screenshots