# Write large number to JSON file

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to do a relatively simple task of writing 1000000000000000000000 (as a number without quotes) to a json file using NodeJs. I have this number defined as a constant:

`const NUM = 1000000000000000000000`

If I simply write it, it comes out as `1e+21`. Everything else I tried (big number...) ends up converting it to a string.

Can someone please help?

**Update**

To clarify what i am after, please look at the code below:

```
// 22 digits
const bigNum = 1000000000000000000000;
console.log(JSON.stringify(bigNum)); // Output: 1e+21

// 19 digits
const bigNum2 = 1000000000000000000;
console.log(JSON.stringify(bigNum2));  // Output: 1000000000000000000
```

What i would like is to be able to output `1000000000000000000000` in the first example instead of 1e+21

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON integers: limit on size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502398/json-integers-limit-on-size)

Answer (score 0):

> If I simply write it, it comes out as 1e+21. Everything else I tried (big number...) ends up converting it to a string.

JSON will always be a string in its serialized representation. It also does not impose any limits on number sizes, although you might of course hit limits imposed by the runtime you use to serialize your data into JSON:

```
> let num = JSON.stringify(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1)
undefined
> JSON.parse(num)
9007199254740992
> Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1
9007199254740992
```

---

The exponential notation does not change the value but just saves bytes and is easier to read:

```
> 1e+21 === 1000000000000000000000
true
```

Comment: "*JSON will always be a string*" OP seems to just have regular code they call "JSON" when it isn't: `const NUM = 1000000000000000000000`

Comment: Hmm. Then how would the Number be converted to a String though?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit unclear. OP also mentions BigInt but that's not serialisable to JSON. I'm not totally sure *what* is happening.