# What is the idiomatic way to find the underlying type of a JsonElement value?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

.NET 6, C# 10, System.Text.Json

Assuming a `JsonElement` that has a `ValueKind` of `Number`, the `JsonElement`'s value could have an underlying type of `int`, `decimal`, `double`, etc.  To find this underlying type, one could run the through a series of tests such as `TryGetInt32()`, `TryGetInt64()`, `TryGetDouble()`, etc.

Is this the best practice, or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: You should be able to use just `TryGetDecimal`, as the `Decimal` type is able to represent all JSON `number` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR:

- If you *know* the JSON number value will be an integer, then use `GetInt64` /`TryGetInt64`.

  - Don't use `GetInt32` or `TryGetInt32` unless you *know* you can.
- Otherwise, just use `Decimal`, as in:`JsonElement.TryGetDecimal` and `JsonElement.GetDecimal`.
- The .NET `Decimal` type can represent practically every JSON `number` value with full precision, regardless of if it's an integer `number`, e.g. `{ "value": 1234 }` or a non-integer `number`, e.g. `{ "value": 12.34 }` in the source JSON.

  - ...the only exception is JSON numbers outside the range -2<sup>96</sup> to 2<sup>96</sup> or with precision beyond 2 / 10<sup>28</sup>.

    - That's 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 and 0.0000000000000000000000000002 respectively.
  - It's highly unlikely you'll encounter those kinds of extreme values in a JSON document because even [though the JSON spec itself imposes no numeric limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502398/json-integers-limit-on-size), most JS environments and JSON libraries operate on the assumption that integer numbers never exceed JS's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (that's 2<sup>53</sup>, or 9,007,199,254,740,991).

    - ...as for non-integer values: that depends entirely on the application: statistical or scientific computing applications might have JSON documents with huge, but imprecise, `double` values in it - in which case using `TryGetDouble` or `GetDouble` would be appropriate, so always check with your project requirements first.
- In general, avoid using IEEE-754 floating-point types (`Single` and `Double`) as they cannot accurately and precisely represent certain types of numbers which would prevent round-tripping and cause data loss or corruption (e.g. try doing `( 0.001f + 0.004f ) - 0.001f`).

  - [**Especially** for representing financial, currency, or other values where fractional precision *must be maintained*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency): accountants and auditors really don't like to see rounding errors or money otherwise *literally* going missing when it goes through the computer...

---

### In detail:

> Assuming a `JsonElement` that has a `ValueKind` of `Number`, the `JsonElement`'s value could have an underlying type of `int`, `decimal`, `double`, etc.

This assumption is incorrect: the `JsonElement` type does not store or represent JSON `number` values using any specific .NET type: instead the `JsonElement` struct is simply a *view* over the source `JsonDocument`'s serialized JSON data: so essentially a `JsonElement` is really just a (validated) run-of-text over a giant JSON string.

Therefore, when a `JsonElement`'s `ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Number` it just means it wraps a sequence of characters directly representing the serialized JSON `number` value, so *there is no "underlying" value representation*.

...this means that you can use any of the `TryGet...` methods to get a .NET numeric value from a JSON `number` value: the only thing you need to consider is if the .NET type can validly represent the JSON `number` value or not: so...

- If you *know* the JSON file will *always* contain non-`null` integer values under `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` then use `GetInt64` (no need for `TryGetInt64`).
- If you *know* the JSON file will *always* contain non-`null` integer values under 2<sup>32</sup> then use `GetInt32` (no need for `TryGetInt32`).
- If you're unsure if the number might be `null` or not, but know it *will* be an integer value, then *don't use* `TryGetInt64` or `TryGetInt32`, instead check `ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Null` first, and *then* use `GetInt64` or `GetInt32`.

  - This approach means that non-`null`, non-integer values will cause a runtime exception (which you should want, as it's an unexpected *exceptional* circumstance) instead of incorrectly assuming that if `TryGetInt32` returns `false` then the `JsonElement` "must" be `null`, which is wrong.
- If you're prototyping, using a REPL, or otherwise messing-around or playing fast-and-loose with data validation requirements then using `TryGetDecimal` is okay, I guess.

---

Here's a program I wrote to compare how the different methods handle different types of source JSON `number` values:

```cs
Test( @"{ ""value"": 0 }"                );
Test( @"{ ""value"": -1 }"               ); // Negative signed integer.
Test( @"{ ""value"": 512 }"              ); 
Test( @"{ ""value"": 1.005 }"            ); // Non-integer value.
Test( @"{ ""value"": 9007199254740992 }" ); // `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1`
Test( @"{ ""value"": 3.7e-5 }"           ); // Small fractional number.
Test( @"{ ""value"": 9.99e300 }"         ); // Outside the range of Decimal and Single, but within Double's range.

static void Test( String json )
{
    JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse( json );
    
    JsonElement valueProp = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("value");

    valueProp.Dump();
    
    List<( String method, Boolean ok, Object? value )> list = new();

    // Decimal:
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetDecimal), ok: valueProp.TryGetDecimal( out Decimal dec ), value: dec ) );

    // IEEE-754:
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetDouble), ok: valueProp.TryGetDouble( out Double dbl ), value: dbl ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetSingle), ok: valueProp.TryGetSingle( out Single sng ), value: sng ) );

    // Unsigned integers:
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetUInt64), ok: valueProp.TryGetUInt64( out UInt64 u64 ), value: u64 ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetUInt32), ok: valueProp.TryGetUInt32( out UInt32 u32 ), value: u32 ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetUInt16), ok: valueProp.TryGetUInt16( out UInt16 u16 ), value: u16 ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetByte), ok: valueProp.TryGetByte  ( out Byte   u8  ), value: u8  ) );

    // Signed integers:
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetInt64), ok: valueProp.TryGetInt64( out Int64 s64 ), value: s64 ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetInt32), ok: valueProp.TryGetInt32( out Int32 s32 ), value: s32 ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetInt16), ok: valueProp.TryGetInt16( out Int16 s16 ), value: s16 ) );
    list.Add( ( nameof(valueProp.TryGetSByte), ok: valueProp.TryGetSByte( out SByte s8  ), value: s8  ) );

    list.Dump();
}
```

which gives me these results:

---

| Input JSON | `TryGetDecimal` | `TryGetDouble` | `TryGetSingle` | `TryGetUInt64` | `TryGetUInt32` | `TryGetUInt16` | `TryGetByte` | `TryGetInt64` | `TryGetInt32` | `TryGetInt16` | `TryGetSByte` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `{ "value": 0 }` | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| `{ "value": -1 }` | -1 | -1 | -1 |  |  |  |  | -1 | -1 | -1 | -1 |
| `{ "value": 512 }` | 512 | 512 | 512 | 512 | 512 | 512 |  | 512 | 512 | 512 |  |
| `{ "value": 1.005 }` | 1.005 | 1.005 | 1.005 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `{ "value": 9007199254740992 }` | 9007199254740992 | 9007199254740992 | 9.007199E+15 | 9007199254740992 |  |  |  | 9007199254740992 |  |  |  |
| `{ "value": 3.7e-5 }` | 0.000037 | 3.7E-05 | 3.7E-05 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `{ "value": 9.99e300 }` |  | 9.99E+300 | ∞ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: _"the .NET Decimal type can represent every JSON number value with full precision"_ I think this is half right. The range of decimal is smaller than double, so decoding big numbers like "1e300" with `GetDecimal` will give you a `FormatException`, while `GetDouble` works.

Comment: @shingo You're right, I'll update my answer.

Comment: RFC-7159 emphasizes interoperability with IEEE-754 - I would personally recommend using `double` rather than `decimal`; if you're producing or receiving JSON that relies on more precision than `double` can provide, you're either in a *very* specialized situation or you're already running the risk of data loss. (I'd suggest using strings for that kind of scenario, to ensure that intermediaries don't lose precision.)

Comment: Thanks @Dai.  In general, for other data types outside of JSON `Number`'s (True, False, String, etc), is using the TryGet methods still the most idiomatic way?

Comment: @chrisxfire "idiomatic" doesn't really apply here - what matters more is how strict or lax you want your JSON processing code to be, and how your program should handle unexpected JSON input. Personally I prefer to fail-fast when any unexpected input is encountered - but other people might have their reasons for being more forgiving (but at risk of letting invalid data through, or failing to handle all classes of input, etc) - but all of this is moot if you use a JSON Schema validation library: if the input is validated as being schema-conforming then you won't need any `TryGet...` methods.